# SQL - Convert results into comma separated string

Tags: sql-server

Using another article on StackOverflow ([How to split date ranges based on months in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985547/how-to-split-date-ranges-based-on-months-in-sql-server-2005)) I have run a `SELECT` statement which splits up a date range by month and returns 2 columns (`DateFrom, DateTo`) in SQL.

```
DECLARE @SDate DATE = '2012/08/01'
DECLARE @EDate DATE = '2013/09/01'

SELECT 
    DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, @SDate) as DateFrom, 
    DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EDate))) as DateTo
FROM 
    master.dbo.spt_values n
WHERE 
    n.Number < DATEDIFF(MONTH, @SDate, @EDate)
    AND n.Type = 'P'
```

I now need to add each of the returned rows into a string separating the columns by `|` (`Dateto|Datefrom`) and each row by `,`.

For example if your run the code above the result would be (just for this example im only using the first 4 rows but I need all of them in one string):

```
R | Date From  |  Date To
1 | 2012-08-01 | 2012-08-31
2 | 2012-09-01 | 2012-09-30
3 | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-30
4 | 2012-11-01 | 2012-11-30
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @stralldates VarChar(MAX)
/* SET @stralldates = INSERTCODE */
PRINT @stralldates
```

What I need PRINT to return:

```
2012-08-01|2012-08-31,2012-10-01|2012-10-30,2012-10-01|2012-10-30,2012-11-01|2012-11-30
```

I have tried several suggestions from other similar questions on StackOverflow (such as `CONCAT`) with no success.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set @StrAllDates = 
  stuff((select ','+convert(char(10), SDate, 121)+'|'+convert(char(10), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, SDate)), 121)
         from (
              select dateadd(month, n.number, @SDate) as SDate
              from master..spt_values as n
              where n.number < datediff(month, @SDate, @EDate) and
                    n.type = 'P'
              ) as T
         order by SDate
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I only know Oracle which provides wm_concat (undocumented) or listagg depending on version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below script to get the data in the format you want to. It basically uses the coalesce method for concatenanation. I created a temp table to hold the data which is then used to iterate over the rows.

```
DECLARE @SDate DATE = '2012/08/01'
DECLARE @EDate DATE = '2013/09/01'
SELECT 
    DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, @SDate) as DateFrom, 
    DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EDate))) as DateTo
INTO #tmp_data
FROM master.dbo.spt_values n
WHERE 
n.Number < DATEDIFF(MONTH, @SDate, @EDate)
AND n.Type = 'P'

declare @my_string varchar(8000);
select @my_string = 
    coalesce( @my_string + ',', '') 
    + convert(varchar(10), d.DateFrom, 126) 
    + '|' + convert(varchar(10), d.DateTo, 126)  
from #tmp_data d
order by d.DateFrom
select @my_string

drop table #tmp_data
```

Also, if you want to use the row rumber, you can use use it by adding another column to the select clause - `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n.Number) as RowNum`

Comment: This answer does not guarantee that dates are concatenated in ascending date order. Only OP will know if that is a problem or not.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson I didn't realise that you could only mark one answer, I'm guessing that using temptables wouldn't be as efficient anyway. But thanks for your help siddharth!

Comment: Thanks Ben. @MikaelEriksson - We can always add an order by clause when selecting from the temp table.

Comment: Concatenating strings like this is undocumented and the correct behavior is undefined even with an order by clause. [Why SQL Server Ignores vaules in string concatenation when ORDER BY clause specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538187/why-sql-server-ignores-vaules-in-string-concatenation-when-order-by-clause-speci)

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you the required comma seperated string:

```
DECLARE @Begin DATETIME
DECLARE @End DATETIME
Declare @test Table(startDate datetime, endDate datetime)
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Begin = '20110101', @End = '20120101'

Insert into @test
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, @Begin) DateFrom, DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number+1, @Begin)) DateTo
FROM master.dbo.spt_values n
WHERE 
    n.Number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @begin, @end)
AND n.Type = 'P'

select  @listStr =  COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'')+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), startDate, 120) + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(10),endDate,120) from @test 
select @listStr
```