# months between two dates in sql server with starting and end date of each of them in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

i want to get months between two dates with their starting and end dates.Suppose if i enter startdate as "2017-04-01" and enddate as "2017-07-31", i want list of months i.e April,May,June,July with their starting and end date respectively.Kindly suggest me how it can be achieved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split date ranges based on months in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985547/how-to-split-date-ranges-based-on-months-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 7):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select dateadd(day, 1 - day(@startdate), @startdate) as som,
             eomonth(@startdate) as eom
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, som), eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, som))
      from cte
      where dateadd(month, 1, som) < @enddate
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If you want the name of the month, then you can use `datename(month, som)`.

Comment: eom()?  should be eomonth()

Comment: note: [**`eomonth()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) support begins with SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 4):

Without recursion, using `master.dbo.spt_values` as a substitute for a numbers table:

```
declare @StartDate date = '20170401'
      , @EndDate   date = '20170731';
;with Months as (
  select top (datediff(month,@startdate,@enddate)+1) 
      [Month] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
    , MonthEnd = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate))
  from master.dbo.spt_values
  order by [Month]
)
select * from Months;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FXQJ4048

returns:

```
+------------+------------+
|   Month    |  MonthEnd  |
+------------+------------+
| 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-30 |
| 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-31 |
| 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-30 |
| 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-31 |
+------------+------------+
```

---

When generating a set or sequence in SQL Server, methods that avoid recursion and loops perform significantly better as the number of values increases.

Reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

---

To get the start and end dates of each month within a given range, when the value of the `@StartDate` parameter is not the first day of the month:

The first option is to truncate the `@StartDate` parameter to the first of the month, the second option is to adjust the expressions in the common table expression to truncate the values there:

```
declare @StartDate date = '20170415'
      , @EndDate   date = '20170715';
/* Option 1: truncate @StartDate to the beginning of the month */
--set @StartDate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @StartDate), 0);
/* Option 2: Truncate @StartDate to month in the common table expression: */
;with Months as (
select top (datediff(month,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1) 
    [Month] = dateadd(month
               , datediff(month, 0, @StartDate) + row_number() over (order by number) -1
               , 0)
    , MonthEnd = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month
               , datediff(month, 0, @StartDate) + row_number() over (order by number) 
               ,0))
  from master.dbo.spt_values
  order by [Month]
)
select * from Months;
```

Comment: @SqlZim...how can i get the above same result if i put a random date instead of this startdate and enddate e.g if i put startdate as '2017-04-15' and Enddate as '2017-07-15', i want to get the first date of month and last date of month of months i get

Comment: @avinashss I have updated my answer to show how you can get the start and end of the months when the given value of `@StartDate` is not the first of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

created the schema

```
   create table abc(
      date1 date
    )

//Inserting data into it
    insert into abc values(getdate()), 
    (DATEADD(Month, -1, getdate())),
    (DATEADD(Month, -2, getdate())),
    (DATEADD(Month, -3, getdate())), 
    (DATEADD(Month, -4, getdate()))
```

and finally the `Select` Query to fetch the data between Start date and end date:

```
select (datename(Month, date1)+' '+convert(varchar(2), date1, 103)) as [Date] from abc 
where convert(varchar(10), date1, 120) between '2017-05-02' and '2017-07-02'
```

Another approach to fetch the between two dates data:

```
select (datename(Month, date1)+' '+convert(varchar(2), date1, 103)) as [Date] from abc
where date1 >= (DATEADD(Month, -3, getdate())) AND date1 <=getdate();
```

And the returned result is:

[image]

this is the Fiddle where you can test this query ->  [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/354e7/14)
Simple and easy...good luck bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @Start DATE ='2017-04-01', 
        @End   DATE ='2017-07-31'


SELECT *, Datename(mm, date), 
       Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, date), 0) AS FirstDateOfMonth, 
       Dateadd (dd, -1, Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)) as 
      LastDateOfMonth
FROM   dbo.TableName
WHERE  Cast(date AS DATE) BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

Comment: please add 4 spaces to the start of every line that contains code. you can also select it with click/drag and click the {} button

Answer (score 0):

I created a stored procedure for that, may be you can convert that into user defined Function.
Posting that code below,

```
create procedure ListMonths
@date1 date,@date2 date 
as
begin
create Table #tempTable
(mnth varchar(10))
while @date1<@date2
begin
insert into #tempTable
select DATENAME(month,@date1)
set @date1 = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@date1)
end
select * from #tempTable;
drop table #tempTable;
end
```

To execute the stored procedure:

```
exec ListMonths '2017-04-01','2018-01-31'
```

output

```
+------------+
|   mnth     |
+------------+
| April      |
| May        | 
| June       |
| July       |
| August     |
| September  |
| October    |
| November   |
| December   |
| January    |
+------------+
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwXxZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If this is not just a one-off report, then I would create a calendar table, and use that to "group by". This will also let you do many other date related calculations.
You can find one at [simple calendar](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) or one here at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql)

Then your code could look like this:

```
SELECT top 10000 * FROM dbo.calendar DD
WHERE DD.TimeStampFrom>='2017-04-01' AND DD.TimeStampFrom <='2017-07-31'
AND DAY(DD.TimeStampFrom)=1
```