# SQL - Select all row that exist between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
employee       | wrok_from     |until
-------------------------------------------
Emp1           | 2017-01-01    |2017-01-15
Emp2           | 2017-01-10    |2017-01-25
Emp3           | 2017-01-20    |2017-02-10
Emp4           | 2017-01-30    |2017-02-20
```

I want to show every employee that work between two dates.
exp: 
when I select date between 2017-01-23 and 2017-02-20 it will show me :

```
Emp2           | 2017-01-10    |2017-01-25
Emp3           | 2017-01-20    |2017-02-10
Emp4           | 2017-01-30    |2017-02-20
```

when I select date between 2017-01-10 and 2017-02-01 it will show me :

```
Emp1           | 2017-01-01    |2017-01-15
Emp2           | 2017-01-10    |2017-01-25
Emp3           | 2017-01-20    |2017-02-10
Emp4           | 2017-01-30    |2017-02-20
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does MySQL support `OVERLAPS`?

Comment: did you try `Between`?!?

Comment: I know how to use between. but still I could't find the answer.

Comment: Please, see this Link -> [Answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460963/months-between-two-dates-in-sql-server-with-starting-and-end-date-of-each-of-the/45462621#45462621)

Comment: Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A *starts* before Event B *ends*, and *ends* after Event B *starts*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.
I used `:start` and `:end` as placeholders for your input  values.

The query selects all employees with their working dates when the working date is at least partially part of your input range.

Visualization (`I`: input range, `y`: selected, `n`: not selected):

```
--------IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII----------
--nnn-yyyy---yyyy---------yyyyy----nn-
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM workdates
WHERE     
    work_from < :end AND
    until > :start
```

Comment: It's really quite simple:  Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A *starts* before Event B *ends*, and *ends* after Event B *starts*.

Comment: @Strawberry That's correct and much easier. Thank you for the hint, I changed the answer.